# Akka Typed actor in play websocket

Tags: java, websocket, akka, actor, playframework-2.3

I'm developing a web-socket application in play and using actor based websocket implementation according to their official tutorial (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaWebSockets)

In controller

```
 public WebSocket socket() {
    System.out.println("socket connecton received");
    return WebSocket.Text.accept(
            request -> ActorFlow.actorRef(WebSocketActor::props, actorSystem, materializer));
}
```

WebSocketActor is implemented with Typed actors as below

```
public class WebSocketActor extends AbstractBehavior<String> {
```

But the issue is it is giving me following error
**Incompatible types: ActorRef is not convertible to ActorRef** and it seems like ActorFlow.actorRef is only allows un-typed actors.

How can I use a Typed Actor with above implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there are missing APIs for typed (I think this is the case with the Play ActorFlow) you can adapt the new typed APIs to the classic ones using `akka.actor.typed.javadsl.Adapter`, like so: `Adapter.toClassic(typedActorRef)`

More docs on coexisting typed and classic APIs here: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/coexisting.html

Comment: Yes you can use coexistence but what I need is to build  purely typed actors. No need to mix typed and un-typed actors. But yes I agree what you said. Indeed it seems there is a mission API for this as of I'm writing this so I'm marking your answer as accepted. Please update this answer if someone found anything otherwise.